# Gitlab Project API Inquiry

Tags: api, gitlab

Is it possible to to filter the gitlab project api by date. An example of this would be to identified all the projects that were modified last week.

I reviewed the documentation but could not see this called out. https://gitlab.com/help/api/projects.md

- Does anyone have an idea of a way to accomplish this other than file tracking?

Answer (score 0):

From the document you linked, it looks like you can `Get /projects` and then add the attribute `order_by`. So you can add something like:

`GET /projects?order_by=last_activity_at`

Comment: Sorry i know you can do an order_by based on the last_activity_at or created_at. However I was thinking more around the line of 

GET /projects?last_activity_after=2018-05-03T08:27:20.1904686-04:00

Comment: @alphao Oh I see, I misunderstood your question, sorry! It looks like you might have to do some mangling of data, and use the `last_activity_at`, and then parse that to get the last week or so projects that were modified.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I suspected so too